# Sorting a data in php. Only variables can be passed by reference

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7

I'm fairly new to php, i am trying to sort users in ascending order by their first and last names. I have tried this but keep getting `can't pass values by reference`. How can i do this

```
foreach( $users->result() as $user ):
            if ($user->first_name != '' && !$user->block):
                $user_list[$user->id] = sort($user->first_name . '' . $user->last_name);
            endif;
        endforeach;
```

Comment: `sort` takes an array as parameter, you are trying to feed it a simple string - that makes no sense whatsoever to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a string to the method sort(). I am assuming this is from the database, under such cases I would usually sort it using SQL first.

But nevertheless to achieve what you want.

```
$user_list=array();
foreach( $users->result() as $user ):
            if ($user->first_name != '' && !$user->block):
                $user_list[$user->id] = $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name
            endif;
        endforeach;

sort($user_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $users->result() as $user ) {
    if ($user->first_name != '' && !$user->block) {
        $user_list[$user->id] = $user->first_name . '' . $user->last_name;
    }
}

$user_list = asort($user_list); //sorted array
```